# How do I capture an html content in angular and then save it to a DB and then load it?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to make an odontogram in my project, however I want once the odontrogram is filled to capture it and save it in a database and then load it when I need it.

In my html create a <ng-template #odontogram> tag

```html
<p>sports works!</p>


<div>
  <ng-template #odontograma>
    <div>
      <svg height="50" width="50" id="p18" #p18>
        <polygon points="10,15 15,10 50,45 45,50" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l1)" id="l1"
                 #p18l1 />
        <polygon points="45,10 50,15 15,50 10,45" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l2)" id="l2"
                 #p18l2 />
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="16" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l3)" id="l3" #p18l3 />
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l4)" id="l4" #p18l4 />
        <polygon points="50,10 40,10 10,26 10,32 46,32 10,50 20,50 50,36 50,28 14,28" fill="white" stroke="black"
                 (click)="changeColor(p18l5)" id="l5" #p18l5 />
        <polygon points="10,10 50,10 40,20 20,20" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l6)" id="l6"
                 #p18l6 />
        <polygon points="50,10 50,50 40,40 40,20" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l7)" id="l7"
                 #p18l7 />
        <polygon points="50,50 10,50 20,40 40,40" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l8)" id="l8"
                 #p18l8 />
        <polygon points="10,50 20,40 20,20 10,10" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l9)" id="l9"
                 #p18l9 />
        <polygon points="20,20 40,20 40,40 20,40" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p18l10)" id="l10"
                 #p18l10 />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>
      <svg height="50" width="50" id="p19" #p19>
        <polygon points="10,15 15,10 50,45 45,50" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l1)" id="l1"
                 #p19l1 />
        <polygon points="45,10 50,15 15,50 10,45" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l2)" id="l2"
                 #p19l2 />
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="16" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l3)" id="l3" #p19l3 />
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l4)" id="l4" #p19l4 />
        <polygon points="50,10 40,10 10,26 10,32 46,32 10,50 20,50 50,36 50,28 14,28" fill="white" stroke="black"
                 (click)="changeColor(p19l5)" id="l5" #p19l5 />
        <polygon points="10,10 50,10 40,20 20,20" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l6)" id="l6"
                 #p19l6 />
        <polygon points="50,10 50,50 40,40 40,20" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l7)" id="l7"
                 #p19l7 />
        <polygon points="50,50 10,50 20,40 40,40" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l8)" id="l8"
                 #p19l8 />
        <polygon points="10,50 20,40 20,20 10,10" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l9)" id="l9"
                 #p19l9 />
        <polygon points="20,20 40,20 40,40 20,40" fill="white" stroke="black" (click)="changeColor(p19l10)" id="l10"
                 #p19l10 />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="amarillo()">Amarillo</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="rojo()">Rojo</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="guardarOdonto()">Guardar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="cargarOdonto()">Cargar</button>
  </div>
```

where will all the teeth be now from the TS I have the following

```
export class CanvasOdontogramaComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  fillColor: String = "white";
  fill;
  htmlString: string;
  nativo: any;
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true }) odontoTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
  odontoContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.odontoContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.odontoTemplate);
  }

  changeColor(lado: HTMLElement) {
    this.fill = this.fillColor;
    lado.attributes.setNamedItem(
      lado.attributes.getNamedItem("fill")
    ).value = this.fill;
  }

  amarillo() {
    this.fillColor = "yellow";
  }

  rojo() {
    this.fillColor = "red";
  }

  guardarOdonto() {
    // this.htmlString = odonto.innerHTML;
    this.nativo = this.odontoTemplate;
    console.log(this.nativo);
    localStorage.setItem('html',this.nativo.toString())
  }
  cargarOdonto() {
    this.odontoTemplate = this.nativo;
  }
}
```

At the moment I am saving it in the local storage to see what information to save but the only thing that I can capture is this [object Object] and I want to capture all the html as a string and also save it in a database I am working with angular 10, thank you very much

Comment: Are you storing the whole html template of odontrogram in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect your element and extract the element you need.

```
  guardarOdonto() {
    // this.htmlString = odonto.innerHTML;
    // this.htmlString = odonto.innerHTML;
    this.nativo = this.odontoTemplate;
    const svgElements: NodeList = this.nativo.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.querySelectorAll(
      "svg"
    ) as NodeList;
    let toStore = "";
    svgElements.forEach(
      (node: SVGElement) => (toStore = "<div>" + node.innerHTML + "</div>")
    );
    console.log(toStore);
    localStorage.setItem("html", toStore);
  }
```

[See this Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enwrvt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcanvas-odontograma%2Fcanvas-odontograma.component.ts)